# jQuery datepicker - Disable all dates after the first disabled date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm creating a booking system and I'm using jQuery's datepicker to allow the user to select the start and end dates of the booking.

My first requirement is that a user cannot pick a date in the past. I've solved that by using the `min date` option.

I've then disabled all dates in the 'end_date' that fall before the 'start_date' using the `onSelect` option.

Next, I've disabled all of the dates that are already booked by using ajax to retrieve a url that returns all of the dates that are already booked, and then using the `beforeShowDay` option to disable them.

Now, what I'd like to do is to disable all of the dates after the first disabled date.

[image: booking calendar]

In the attached image you'll see that the 15th has been selected as the start date. The 20th - 24th and the 27th - 30th are already booked.

Because the user cannot book from the 15th - 25th. I'd like to disable all dates that fall after the 19th so that the user can only book dates that run concurrently.

I've included my code below. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
var bookedDates;
var dateToday = new Date();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/panels/" + this.value + "/bookings",
  success: function(data) {
    bookedDates = JSON.stringify(data);
    $('#start_date').datepicker('destroy');
    $('#end_date').datepicker('destroy');
    $('#start_date').datepicker({
      minDate: dateToday,
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [bookedDates.indexOf(string) == -1]
      },
      onSelect: function(date) {
        $('#end_date').removeAttr('disabled');
        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
        //Set Minimum Date of EndDatePicker After Selected Date of StartDatePicker
        $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', endDate);
        $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', '+2y');
      }
    });

    $('#end_date').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [bookedDates.indexOf(string) == -1]
      }
    });

  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#start_date').datepicker('destroy');
    $('#end_date').datepicker('destroy');
    $('#start_date').datepicker({
      minDate: dateToday,
      onSelect: function(date) {
        $('#end_date').removeAttr('disabled');
        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
        //Set Minimum Date of EndDatePicker After Selected Date of StartDatePicker
        $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', endDate);
        $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', '+2y');
      }
    });
    $('#end_date').datepicker({});
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what dates should be allowed.

Comment: When choosing the date only the available dates that run concurrently should be allowed. In this instance the 15th has been chosen and the available dates that run concurrently go up to the 19th. The dates that should be allowed when the 15th is chosen is the 16th, 17th, 18th and 19th.

Comment: You will have to have some additional process in `befofeShowDay` that will look at date and date + 1d.